# starting DDMS programmatically

Tags: android

I am working with automation.I want to start DDMS through my program and take the heap dump of the application programmatically . That is,instead of the clicking on the heap dump button i want to take the dump through program.Is that possible? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Debug.dumpHprofData(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#dumpHprofData%28java.lang.String%29) to generate [a heap dump](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html).

> Dump "hprof" data to the specified file. This may cause a GC.

No DDMS needed.

Comment: can i include this dumHprofData method in my test project to take the dump of the application i am testing